# how to I disable management url in jboss

Tags: jboss7.x

i am using subnet-match in jboss 7.1.1 Final standalone.xml file for the management http url.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <subnet-match value="10.62.65.0/254"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

but i can still access the management url from other subnets.

is there anything else i need to configure?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

To disable management url you can just bind it to localhost, which is default anyhow.
this way url won't be accessible from any remote machine.

To completely disable it, you can just remove whole

```
<management-interfaces> 
...
</management-interfaces>
```

from standalone.xml